# Importing JSON data from URL

Tags: python

```
import json

url_adress1 = 'https://blackboard.ljmu.ac.uk/bbcswebdav/pid-3746902-dt-
content-
rid-10963300_2/courses/3106FNDET-201617-SEM-2/queue%281%29.json'

with open('queue') as url_adress1:
data = json.load(url_adress1)

print ("\n")

with open('stock') as data_file:
data = json.load(data_file)

url_address  = 'https://blackboard.ljmu.ac.uk/bbcswebdav/pid-3746902-dt-
content-rid-10964001_2/courses/3106FNDET-201617-SEM-2/stock%281%29.json'
```

I have a question which i have been trying to research for the most of today but i cant seem to find a way to import a **JSON** files data from a URL. I have this work to complete by tonight so im stressing. There are 2 JSON files which contain a list of names with their preferred fruit, and the second one contains how many fruit there is to give out.

Comment: have a look at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Answer (score 1):

You are parsing the string, not the content in JSON format from the host you are accessing. You should do a request and then parse it. Try this:

```
import urllib, json
url = "https://blackboard.ljmu.ac.uk/bbcswebdav/pid-3746902-dt-content-rid-10964001_2/courses/3106FNDET-201617-SEM-2/stock%281%29.json"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
print(json.loads(response.read()))
```